# Table incorrectly marked as Incorrectly formatted code

Tags: bug, stackexchange, markdown

I have a simplistic table [I posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/286932). Obviously, If it is marked as unformatted code, then I can only post an image here. I will attempt to post it here, and include a meta-screenshot. I propose that tables on Code Review are not subject to code-formatting rules, to alleviate this issue.
[image: A table describing a fictional Instruction-set-architecture]

```
| ID  | Opcode | Description                   |
| --- | ------ | ----------------------------- |
| 0   | ADD    | A <-- A + B, overflow         |
| 1   | JOTO   | Jump if overflow, and toggle  |
| 2   | LIT    | B <-- Literal value following |
| 3   | LOAD   | B <-- Mem[I]                  |
| 4   | STOR   | Mem[I] <-- B                  |
| 5   | SWAP   | Swap A and B registers        |
| 6   | SWPI   | Swap B and I registers        |
| 7   | INC    | A <-- A + 1, overflow         |
| 8   | NOP    | Clears overflow               |
```

*PS: I tripped up *seven* times on the image, clicking it as if to edit the post.

Comment: Repoed on [a non-moderator account](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/242240/phroggie). My moderator account bypassed the check.